# iOS 10: The action button in alert controller does not shifts to bottom if the height of alert controller is increased

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "What do you want to do?", preferredStyle: .alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        alertController.view.addConstraint(height)

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: AlerController is default. You are'nt supposed to add constraints to it. Use custom views if you want different behaviors

Comment: I am facing this issue in iOS 10.It works very well in ios 11 and onwards.

Comment: The fact that it works in iOS 11 doesn't make it supported behavior.

Comment: Add some screen shots for our reference

Answer (score 0):

This is not the intended behavior of `UIAlertController`, per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller):

> **Important**
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and
>   does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
>   private and must not be modified.